# Redirect for logout Spring Security

Tags: java, spring

I use the following Spring security configuraiton for my    @Override

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
        .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/signup").permitAll()
        .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
            .logout().logoutUrl("/logout").logoutSuccessUrl("/login").deleteCookies("auth_code").invalidateHttpSession(true)
        .and()
        // We filter the api/signup requests
        .addFilterBefore(
            new JWTSignupFilter("/signup", authenticationManager(),
                    accountRepository, passwordEncoder),
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
        // We filter the api/login requests
        .addFilterBefore(
            new JWTLoginFilter("/login", authenticationManager()),
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
        // And filter other requests to check the presence of JWT in
        // header
        .addFilterBefore(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(userDetailsServiceBean()),
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
}
```

I want browser to be redirected to `/login` URL in result of successful logout. But I get this response:

```
{
  "timestamp": 1493871686489,
  "status": 404,
  "error": "Not Found",
  "message": "No message available",
  "path": "/login"
}
```

**Edit 1**

I have a login filter which captures POST requests to the `/login` endpoint:

```
public class JWTLoginFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {


    public JWTLoginFilter(String url, AuthenticationManager authManager) {
        super(new AntPathRequestMatcher(url, "POST"));
        setAuthenticationManager(authManager);
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest req,
            HttpServletResponse res) throws AuthenticationException,
            IOException, ServletException {

        CustomUserDetails creds = new ObjectMapper().readValue(
                req.getInputStream(), CustomUserDetails.class);

        return getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(creds.getUsername(),
                        creds.getPassword()));
    }

    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest req,
            HttpServletResponse res, FilterChain chain, Authentication auth) {
        TokenAuthenticationService.addAuthentication(res, auth.getName());
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2**

The following rest controller doesn't get hit !

```
@RestController
public class UserAcccountController {
    @Autowired
    AccountRepository accountRepository;

    @RequestMapping(path = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String loginGet() {
        return "/login";
    }

    @RequestMapping(path = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void loginPost(HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) {
        httpServletResponse.setHeader("Location", "/home");
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you actually have code set up at "/login"? Can you post a sample of your controller?

Comment: I have it as a filter. I will add it to the post in a sec.

Comment: What is actually mapping the "/login" URL to your controller? AFAIK, just overriding the authentication methods won't achieve that.

Comment: I created a controller for the `/login` endpoint for `POST` and `GET`. But it doesn't get hit. I edit the post and add to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to add the controller I included in Edit 2 and I also had to edit the `successfulAuthentication` in the login filter to the following:

```
@Override
protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest req,
        HttpServletResponse res, FilterChain chain, Authentication auth) {
    TokenAuthenticationService.addAuthentication(res, auth.getName());
    chain.doFilter(req, res);
}
```